# Mean of column in PySpark without using collect

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, mean

I have a dataframe that looks like below

```
accuracy
--------
91.0
92.0
73.0
72.0
88.0
```

I am using aggregate, count and collect to get the column sum which is taking too much time. Below is my code

```py
total_count = df.count()
total_sum=df.agg({'accuracy': 'sum'}).collect()
total_sum_val = [i[0] for i in total_sum]
acc_top_k = (total_sum_val[0]/total_count)*100
```

Is there any alternative method to get the mean accuracy in PySpark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you  can aggregate the column values and calculate the average. Then, extract it into the variable.

```py
df = df.agg(F.avg('accuracy'))
acc_top_k = df.head()[0] * 100
```

Full test:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([(91.0,), (92.0,), (73.0,), (72.0,), (88.0,)], ['accuracy'])

df = df.agg(F.avg('accuracy'))
acc_top_k = df.head()[0] * 100

print(acc_top_k)
# 8220.0
```

If you prefer, you can use your method too:
`df = df.agg({'accuracy': 'avg'})`